# How to use async/await in .ts file ( I get error : " async functions are only available when targeting ecmascript 6 or higher" )

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, es6-promise

At first .. my project contains only app.js(expressJS) that is one main file and this file has many line of code. my dev manager order me refactor code and split some function in to another .ts file ( migrate from javascript to typescript )

My first .js before I migrate to .ts has asyn function after I migrate my code in to .ts I get a error about

> async functions are only available when targeting ecmascript 6 or higher

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I found the solution that I have to target to es6 in tsconfig.json but I don't know where is tsconfig.js I have only package.json before I migrate its.

Can you help me to solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: what bundler are you using? Is this Angular? React? Vue? etc.

Comment: Now its on dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

The default target for Typescript is "ES3". Since you are not using tsconfig.json in your application the default compiler options are selected. If you wish to continue without using tsconfig.json you can use the following command:

```
tsc --target "ES6"
```

Or you can add a tsconfig.json to the application and use that.

For the default compiler options refer: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

For knowing more about tsconfig.json refer: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I try to create tsconfig.json at package.json level. Is it true?
And in this file i set target : "es6"  and files : "src/myfile.ts". I still get error same a previous.

Comment: @KittinunPongsukjai Your tsconfig.json would contain the following JSON object: `{ compilerOptions: { target: 'ES6' } }`. I'm assuming you missed the `compilerOptions` as parent property

Comment: my tsconfig.json = {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"es6"
  },
  "files": [
    "function/Translator.ts"
  ]
}
. I still get error what wrong with my solution?

Comment: @KittinunPongsukjai try this : `tsc --p <path to tsconfig.json>` to specify the tsconfig.json to use while compiling.
If the above does not work, try specifying the command inline `tsc --target ES6`.

Comment: i get this error after i use command : tsc --p mypath , tsc --target ES6 
"node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts:621:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent propert
y declarations must have the same type.  Property 'prototype' must be of type 'W
eakSet<object>', but here has type 'WeakSet<any>'."

Comment: @KittinunPongsukjai node and express do not have a built-in support for Typescript. You would need to include express-ts and @types/express in your application. Refer this: https://dev.to/briandgls/using-typescript-with-express--e0k . 
I had missed the part where you mentioned you were doing this for an express app.